# How to store input data using python3 into text file and print the data output?

Tags: python-3.x, file, user-input, store

I'm completely new to python so I don't know what I'm supposed to make a data by using user input into text file. All I can do is using data variables into input(). I tried using input to make a data into text file but after that, there's nothing in the text file. Any other ways to solve this?

```
import sys

def write(nameOfFile):
        name = nameOfFile+'.txt';

        file = open(name, 'w+');


        upper_code = input();
        lower_code = input();
        name_code = input();
first_code = input();
        day = input();
        date_start = input();
        date_end = input();
        hours = input();
        num_code = input();

        print(name);

        print(upper_code, lower_name);
 print(name_code, first_code);
 print(day, date_start, date_end);
 print(hours);
 print(num_code);

        return name;

if len(sys.argv)<2:
        print('usage: makefile <filename.txt>');
        print('Enter a file name: ');
        inputFi = input();
        write(inputFi);
```

Those are the variables I'm using in python:

```
upper_code lower_code
name_code first_code
day date_start date_end
hours
num_code
```

and this is a file.txt that supposed to looks like this:

```
ABC abc
Rider I
TH 10/30/20 10/31/20
4
16
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import sys

def write(nameOfFile):

    with open(nameOfFile + '.txt', 'w+') as input_stream:

            upper_code = input('user code: ')
            lower_code = input('lower code: ')
            name_code = input('name code: ')
            first_code = input('first code: ')
            day = input('day: ')
            date_start = input('date start: ')
            date_end = input('date end: ')
            hours = input('hours: ')
            num_code = input('num code: ')

            print(upper_code, lower_code, file=input_stream)
            print(name_code, first_code, file=input_stream)
            print(day, date_start, date_end, file=input_stream)
            print(hours, file=input_stream)
            print(num_code, file=input_stream)

if len(sys.argv)<2:
    print('usage: makefile <filename.txt>')
    print('Enter a file name: ')
    inputFi = input()
    write(inputFi)
```

Output:

```
$ python3 writetofile.py
usage: makefile <filename.txt>
Enter a file name: 
file
user code: ABC
lower code: abc
name code: Rider
first code: I
day: TH
date start: 10/30/20
date end: 10/31/20
hours: 4
num code: 16

$ cat file.txt 
ABC abc
Rider I
TH 10/30/20 10/31/20
4
16
```

BTW you don't need to use semicolons in Python, you can learn more about the Python style guide [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Also if you want to learn more about writing and reading files in Python you can read [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html).